# Improving BeautifulSoup Perf

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup, mechanize, delicious-api

SO I have the following set of code parsing delicious information. It prints data from a Delicious page in the following format

Bookmark | Number of People

Bookmark | Number of People
etc...

I used to use the following method to find this info.

```
def extract (soup):
    links = soup.findAll('a',rel='nofollow')
    for link in links:
        print >> outfile, link['href']

    hits = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'delNavCount'})
    for hit in hits:
        print >> outfile, hit.contents


#File to export data to
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")

#Browser Agent
br = Browser()    
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]


url= "http://www.delicious.com/asd"
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
extract(soup)
```

But the problem was that some bookmarks didnt have a number of people, so I decided to parse it different so that I would get the data concurrently and print out the bookmarks and number of people side by side.

EDIT: Got it from 15 - 5 seconds with this updated version, any more suggestions

```
def extract (soup):
    bookmarkset = soup.findAll('div', 'data')
    for bookmark in bookmarkset:
        link = bookmark.find('a',)
        vote = bookmark.find('span', 'delNavCount')
        try:
            print >> outfile, link['href'], " | " ,vote.contents
        except:
            print >> outfile, "[u'0']"
    #print bookmarkset


#File to export data to
outfile = open("output.txt", "w")

#Browser Agent
br = Browser()    
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]


url= "http://www.delicious.com/asd"
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
extract(soup)
```

The performance on this is terrible though, takes 17 secs to parse the first page, and around 15 secs thereafter on a pretty decent machine. It significantly degraded when going from the first bit of code to the second bit. Is there anything I can do to imporve perf here?

Comment: Note also that `class` is the second positional argument with `find`/`findAll`, so you could do `soup.find('div', 'data')` and `bookmark.findAll('span', 'delNavCount')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you are assigning to `vote` – twice. The first assignment is unnecessary and indeed quite heavy, since it must parse the whole document – on each iteration. Why?

```
   vote = BeautifulSoup(html)
   vote = bookmark.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'delNavCount'})
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are concerned about performance you might have a look at something that talks to the delicious API, rather than screen-scraping, ie [pydelicious](http://code.google.com/p/pydelicious/).  For example:

```
>>> import pydelicious
>>> pydelicious.get_userposts('asd')
[{'extended': '', 'description': u'Ksplice - System administration and software blog', 'tags': u'sysadm, blog, interesting', 'url': u'http://blog.ksplice.com/', 'user': u'asd'
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup does a lot more than what you need in this instance. If you really want to crank up the speed, then I would suggest taking a more basic approach of urllib + a simple line-by-line parser.

Parsing a page the size of the "asd" example should take well under one second on a modern machine.